# Invalid object name [dbo].[TriggerName]

Tags: sql-server, object, triggers, alter

I created a trigger named `UPDATE_MERCHANDISE`. The query completed with one error, a simple typo. I fixed the typo and changed the code to `ALTER TRIGGER`, but now when I try to execute it I receive the error

> Invalid object name [dbo].[UPDATE_MERCHANDISE]

Why would it be valid when I created it, but not when I try to alter it? Any and all help/ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks.

```
USE [CIS31038]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[UPDATE_MERCHANDISE] ON [dbo].[ORDERITEM]
AFTER INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @ITEMID VARCHAR(2)
DECLARE @TOTAL INT

--INSERT CASE
IF(EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INSERTED) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DELETED))
BEGIN
DECLARE INSERT_CURSOR CURSOR FOR
SELECT ITEMID, SUM(QUANTITY) AS TOTAL
FROM INSERTED
GROUP BY ITEMID

OPEN INSERT_CURSOR
FETCH NEXT FROM INSERT_CURSOR INTO @ITEMID, @TOTAL
WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    UPDATE MERCHANDISE
    SET QUANTITYONHAND = QUANTITYONHAND - @TOTAL
    WHERE ITEMID = @ITEMID
    FETCH NEXT FROM INSERT_CURSOR INTO @ITEMID, @TOTAL
END
CLOSE INSERT_CURSOR
DEALLOCATE INSERT_CURSOR
END

--DELETE CASE
IF(EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DELETED) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INSERTED))
BEGIN
DECLARE DELETE_CURSOR CURSOR FOR
SELECT ITEMID, SUM(QUANTITY) AS TOTAL
FROM DELETED
GROUP BY ITEMID

OPEN DELETE_CURSOR
FETCH NEXT FROM DELETE_CURSOR INTO @ITEMID, @TOTAL
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    UPDATE MERCHANDISE
    SET QUANTITYONHAND = QUANTITYONHAND + @TOTAL
    WHERE ITEMID = @ITEMID
    FETCH NEXT FROM DELETE_CURSOR INTO @ITEMID, @TOTAL
END
CLOSE DELETE_CURSOR
DEALLOCATE DELETE_CURSOR
END

--UPDATE CASE
IF(EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INSERTED) AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DELETED))
BEGIN
DECLARE UPDATE_CURSOR CURSOR FOR
SELECT I.ITEMID, SUM(I.QUANTITY - D.QUANTITY) AS TOTAL
FROM INSERTED I INNER JOIN DELETED D ON
     I.PONUMBER = D.PONUMBER AND I.ITEMID = D.ITEMID
GROUP BY I.ITEMID

OPEN UPDATE_CURSOR
FETCH NEXT FROM UPDATECURSOR INTO @ITEMID, @TOTAL
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    UPDATE MERCHANDISE
    SET QUANTITYONHAND = QUANTITYONHAND - @TOTAL
    WHERE ITEMID = @ITEMID
    FETCH NEXT FROM UPDATE_CURSOR INTO @ITEMID, @TOTAL

END
CLOSE UPDATE_CURSOR
DEALLOCATE UPDATE_CURSOR
END
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you had a typo, most likely, the trigger never got created

```
Try CREATE TRIGGER instead of ALTER TRIGGER
```

By the way, generally, you remove the trigger and recreate, using something like.

```
IF Object_id('TRIGGER_NAME') is not null
    DROP TRIGGER Trigger Name
GO
CREATE TRIGGER TriggerName
AS
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you! (It's always something blindingly obvious, isn't it? Haha)