# Triggers in SQL Server - error "Invalid Object Name"

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, triggers

I created this trigger but I get an error

> Invalid object name 'dbo.informacao'

I had another trigger that I deleted but it had a different name. What can the problem? The query compiled without errors so I am assuming I did nothing wrong

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[informacao]
ON [dbo].[FolhaAuxiliar]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @codOperacao int, @codFuncionario int, 
            @codEquipamento int, @dataInicio datetime, 
            @dataFim datetime, @produto int, @folha int,
            @quantP int, @quantD int, @setorFuncionario int

    SELECT 
        @codOperacao = i.CodOperação, 
        @codFuncionario = i.CodFuncionário, 
        @codEquipamento = i.CodEquipamento, 
        @dataInicio = i.DataInicio, 
        @dataFim = i.DataFim,  
        @produto = i.Produto,
        @folha = i.Folha,
        @quantP = i.qntdproduzida,
        @quantD = i.qntddesperdiçada
    FROM 
        inserted i

    SELECT @setorFuncionario = f.Setor
    FROM Funcionário f
    WHERE f.CodFuncionario = @codFuncionario

    IF (@setorFuncionario != 2)
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('O funcionário não pertence ao setor das operações', 10,1);
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        RETURN;
    END
    ELSE IF(@codEquipamento IN (SELECT f.CodEquipamento FROM FolhaAuxiliar f WHERE DataFim IS NULL))
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('O equipamento já está a ser utilizado', 10,1);
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        RETURN;
    END
    ELSE IF (@codFuncionario IN (SELECT f.CodFuncionário FROM FolhaAuxiliar f WHERE DataFim IS NULL))
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('O funcionário já se encontra a realizar outra operação', 10,1);
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        RETURN;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [FolhaAuxiliar](CodOperação, CodFuncionário, CodEquipamento, DataInicio, Produto, Folha, qntdproduzida, qntddesperdiçada, DataFim)
            SELECT 
                CodOperação, CodFuncionário, CodEquipamento, DataInicio, 
                Produto, Folha, qntdproduzida, qntddesperdiçada, DataFim
            FROM 
                inserted
    END
END
```

Comment: See if this helps:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27156053/invalid-object-name-dbo-triggername

Comment: Your trigger *assumes* that a DML statement can only effect one row; that isn't true. A DML statement can effect an unlimited number of rows. As soon as you have 2 or more rows in an `INSERT`/`UPDATE` this will not behave as you expect.

Comment: As for the error, it appears to be pretty straight forward. There is no `TRIGGER` `[dbo].[informacao]` to `ALTER`. However, you ***need*** to fix your trigger so handle multiple rows. [Bad habits to kick : abusing triggers](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-abusing-triggers)

Comment: @Larnu I created functions to do those verifications, but I don´t know how to associate them to constraints

Comment: Functions to do what verifications? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: Sounds like you're misunderstanding what Larnu said. You can only `ALTER TRIGGER` if it already exists. Try using `CREATE TRIGGER` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create two or more objects with the same name (schema included) in a DB. You can only alter an object if it's already been created first.

You can also use the following if unsure:

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[informacao]
...
```